# ASP.NET MVC Passing models by ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass a model and an `int` to a controller upon clicking an `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", new { m = Model.UserLookupViewModel, page = Model.UserLookupViewModel.curPage }, null)
```

Does not work, instead it passes a blank instance of the model, which one would expect when using `new`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", Model.UserLookupViewModel, null)
```

Does work.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Lookup(UserLookupViewModel m, int page = 0)
{
    return this.DoLookup(m, page);
}
```

**View model**

```
public class UserLookupViewModel
{
    public int curPage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Forenames")]
    public string Forenames { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DOB")]
    public DateTime? DoB { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Post code")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

How can I pass them together? The `Lookup` method's arguments match the named properties in the ActionLink.

Comment: You can't pass model using ActionLink

Comment: Please post your controller definition and that of the model accepted by it.

Comment: MVC4 allows you to pass the model automatically through URL variables, which is seen my second example.

Comment: The docs for ActionLink show that none of that method's overloads accepts a viewmodel object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx   You can pass RouteValues, as per your second example, but not an entire object.

Comment: Ok I see, I'll review my solution.

Comment: Assuming that the properties of the view model are populated by controls on the page, I would just post a form, show us your razor code.

Comment: Why do you want to use an ActionLink instead of posting a form?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use an ActionLink to pass properties with a Link but you can do the following to get the same behavior.

```
<form action="/url/to/action" Method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="Property" value="hello,world" />
  <button type="submit">Go To User</button>
</form>
```

If you create a helper to generate these **GET** forms, you will be able to style them like they are regular link buttons. The only thing I caution against is that **ALL** forms on the page are susceptible to modification so I wouldn't trust the data. I'd rather just pull the data again when you get to where you are going.

I use the technique above when creating search actions and want to retain a search history and keep the back button working.

Hope this helps,

Khalid :)

---

P.S.

The reason this works.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", Model.UserLookupViewModel, null)
```

Is because the parameter list of the ActionLink method is generalized to take an **object**, so it will take anything. What it will do with that object is pass it to a **RouteValueDictionary** and then try to create a querystring based on the properties of that object.

If you say that method is working above, you could also just try adding a new property to the viewmodel called **Id** and it will work like you wanted it to.

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to serialize your model as a JSON string, and send that to your controller to turn into an object.

Here's your actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", new { JSONModel = Json.Encode(Model.UserLookupViewModel), page = Model.UserLookupViewModel.curPage }, null)
```

In your controller, you'll need a method to turn your JSON data into a MemoryStream:

```
private Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
  writer.Write(s);
  writer.Flush();
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

In your ActionResult, you turn the JSON string into an object:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(string JSONModel, int page)
{
  DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Model.UserLookupViewModel));
  var yourobject =  (UserLookupViewModel)ser.ReadObject(GenerateStreamFromString(JSONModel));
}
```

Comment: Please don't format with snippets when the language used is not displayable by them. It doesn't improve the answer and makes your answer more cluttered. Regular code blocks will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

While I highly suggest you use a form to accomplish what your attempting to do here for security sake.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", new 
      { Forenames = Model.UserLookupViewModel.Forenames, 
        Surname = Model.UserLookupViewModel.Surname, 
        DOB = Model.UserLookupViewModel.DOB,  
        PostCode = Model.UserLookupViewModel.PostCode, 
        page = Model.UserLookupViewModel.curPage }, null)
```

MVC will map the properties appropriately doing this; however, this will use your url to pass the values to the controller. This will display the values for all the world to see.

I highly suggest using a form for security sake especially when dealing with sensitive data such as DOB.

I personally would do something like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Lookup", "User")
 {
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Forenames)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Surname)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DOB)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PostCode)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.curPage)

     <input type="submit" value="Next" />
  }
```

You can have multiple of these type of forms on the page if needed.

Your controller then accepts a post but functions the same way:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Lookup(UserLookupViewModel m, int page = 0)
 {
     return this.DoLookup(m, page);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry buy HiddenFor is NOT safe. It still sends the data to the page for the user to see, it's in the source, just not physically visible on the page.

Comment: Without the "security" note, this answer would make a nice addition to the existing answer because it is the only one using `Html.BeginForm` and `Html.HiddenFor`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
@{
var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary("");
routeValueDictionary.Add("Forenames",Forenames);
routeValueDictionary.Add("Surname",Surname);
routeValueDictionary.Add("DoB ",DoB );
routeValueDictionary.Add("Postcode",Postcode );
routeValueDictionary.Add("Page",PageNum );
// Add any item you want!
}
@html.ActionLink("LinkName", "ActionName", "ControllerName",
routeValueDictionary , new{@class="form-control"})
```