# Server Error in '/' Application in ActionLink (but submit works fine)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Execution of the following lines

```
@Html.ActionLink("Open",actionName: "DownloadExcelFile", 
                        controllerName: "Excel", 
                        routeValues: new { model = new ExcelModel(5, "JobName", "item.UserName") },
                        htmlAttributes: null)
```

returns **Server Error in '/' Application**, could you help me to fix them?

Note that when I change the name of the parameter, **model** -> **id**, I get an **Error 404** instead of **Server Error in '/' Application**.

The **model** is

```
public class ExcelModel
{
    public int InputA { get; set; }
    public string InputB { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ExcelModel(int inputA, string inputB, string userName)
    {
        InputA = inputA;
        InputB = inputB;
        UserName = userName;
    }
    public ExcelModel()
    {
        InputA = 1;
        InputB = "B1";
        UserName = "NiceUser";
    }
    ...
}
```

**Controller** is

```
public class ExcelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ExcelModel(1, "B1", User.Identity.Name);
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadExcelFile(ExcelModel id)
    {
        // assume we create an an excel stream...
        MemoryStream excelStream = id.BuildSpreadsheet();

        return new FileStreamResult(excelStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            FileDownloadName = "myfile.xslx"
        };
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig** is the standard one

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, as mentioned earlier, the method itself is fine, since it works perfectly with **submit**, as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadExcelFile", "Excel"))
{
    <fieldset>
        // fields names and values
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Open Excel"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can't pass an entire class as a route value param. The helper has to be able to put whatever you pass into a URL, which means it has to be something that can be converted to a string value. It might be possible to JSON encode the model and then pass the JSON string for the param, but the helper isn't going to make such assumptions for you, nor would it necessarily know *how* to JSON encode it for you, if it did.

2) When you just pass the id, you get a 404 because your action doesn't not accept an int for `id`, but rather expects `ExcelModel`, which as we discussed in #1, is not possible to pass via URL.

Comment: You were right, I was confused because I was able to pass a blanc instance  of my class, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529092/asp-net-mvc-passing-models-by-actionlink

Answer (score 1):

Your controller method is marked with the [`HttpPost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx) attribute. This means that it only accepts POST-requests and not GET-requests. Normal link visits are GET-requests, so that is probably the problem. ([Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp))

Remove the `HttpPost` attribute and see if that fixes the problem.