# List<Object> passed from view to controller becomes an empty List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a IMDb like ASP.Net website, I want to pass the List of crew members to a different view where I can edit them. However when the List is passed from the Film view to the FilmCastEdit action in FilmController the List count is 0. Am I doing this wrong? another option is to run a new sql query when the FIlmCastEdit is called but seeing the list of people I need is already there I thought this way would be better.

Film view

```
@if (IngelogdeGebruiker != null && IngelogdeGebruiker.TypeOfUser == UserTypeEnum.Moderator)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "FilmCastEdit", "Film", new { castList = Model.Crew }, null)
}
```

Film controller

```
public ActionResult FilmCastEdit(List<Person> castList)
{

    return View(castList);
}
```

Debug view of Film view to Film controller
https://gyazo.com/eb5511ab4154256505aa87403f79f485

 In the Film view Model.Crew count is 5 as you can see

https://gyazo.com/d53df971450865f73c6662da08cfc8f0

 but castList here has a count of 0

If I didn't clarify something important please let me know, I have no clue why this isn't working.

Comment: Yeah, you can't just assign an object instance to a query argument. Did you look and see what the resulting URL was? And, FYI, stackoverflow allows you to post images. Better to post them here than some external site.

Comment: http://localhost:10099/Film/ FilmCastEdit?castList= System.Collections.Generic.List%601% 5BBlueRateITLogicLayer.Models. Person%5D

this is what the url turns in to, I'm not sure what it means I'm new to this.

Comment: added some random spaces in there, it shows now

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "..." is the URL created by `Html.ActionLink()`. I'm sorry. I don't think that's right.

Comment: Your URL you posted Tom is a get request with the literal object description according to MVC as a string appended as a query string. If you were to break and inspect your object, the top level of the model would be descriped as that List Model Collection. What you are seeing is the literal string interpretation of your model, you need to post from the client side.

Comment: Voting to close.  Code for a question needs to be in the question *itself* not in a link offsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a submit/post in order for MVC to do a complex model bind like that, an ActionLink appends the data as a query string so it will only bind on the controller side with multiple individual named/typed fields. Your controller is set up as a post correctly but the actionlink is not a post.

Cheat and create a mini hidden form to submit with that data, set up an ajax post, or send it as a JSON string. There are a number of ways to do this. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26528113/466245

Comment: is it in this case not more efficient to just write an sql query that gets me the cast of a film? It seems like the easier option then reformatting the data to Json and then asking it back again in the controller

Comment: SQL calls are expensive, especially when you think about tons of users pinging a database server for something you have already accessed and have in the front end. A simple JSON encode call is dirt cheap and in reality when you get into the inner workings of the web, this is how it works. The client, the front end, needs a way to communicate with the server, the controller. A database call doesn't do anything for you if you already sent the client the data, and if the data has changed client side then the database won't have those yet unrecorded changes.

Comment: You need to think of the view and the controller as physically residing across the country from one another because in reality, that is how it will be. Your views will be loaded and served up to N number of user's computers where they will interact and send you data back to your server. It has to work like this, otherwise don't use MVC or do web coding, make a traditional windows application.

Comment: allright, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to warp my head around the JSON workaround.